# @OneToMany Bidirectional relation doesn't work correctly

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two tables, Users and Posts. They are linked with ManyToOne/OneToMany:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Basic
@NotNull
@Column(name = "username",nullable = false,unique = true)
private String username;
@Basic
@NotNull
private String password;

@OneToOne
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "picture_id")
private Picture profilePicture;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "followers_users",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "follower_id"))
private Set<User> followers;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followers", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> following;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Comment> comments;
```

...

and also:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Basic
private String caption;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private User user;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "picture_id")
private Picture picture;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
private Set<Comment> comments;
```

...

When I persist a user's new post, user.posts is empty. This is not what I expect. I expect this to be automatically updated when a new post is added.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem,
the problem is that in Controller class I put annotation @Transactional.
To work correctly  @Transactional need to be removed.